# Can there be more than $\log_2(n)$ mutually orthogonal $(\pm1)$-vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_{2k-1} \neq x_{2k}$ for all $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, hadamard-matrices

A [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $n$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $\pm1$ such that any two rows are mutually orthogonal. Any Hadamard matrix must necessarily have order equal to $1$, $2$, or a multiple of $4$. A long-standing conjecture is that this condition is also sufficient for a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ to exist.

I'm trying to show that no Hadamard matrix $H$ can exist under the following restriction on its entries: for each $1 \leq k \leq n/2$, $H_{i,2k-1} \neq H_{i,2k}$, that is, in each row, the consecutive pairs of entries are all $\{\pm1\}$. My stronger guess is that there aren't more than $\log_2(n)$ mutually orthogonal $(\pm1)$-vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that $x_{2k-1} \neq x_{2k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n/2$.

It is easy to get at least $\log_2(n)$ such vectors as follows. Assume $n = 2^m$ for the sake of simplicity. Start with $x_1 = (1,-1,1,-1,\dotsc,1,-1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For $1 < i < m$, view $x_{i-1}$ as $(y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_{2^i})$, each $y_j$ of length $2^{m-i}$, and then define $x_i$ inductively as $x_i = (y_1,-y_2,y_3,-y_4,\dotsc,y_{2^i - 1},-y_{2^i})$. Then, $x_1,\dotsc,x_m$ satisfy the required property. For instance, when $n = 8$, this gives the following three vectors:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= (1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)\\
x_2 &= (1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1)\\
x_3 &= (1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1)
\end{align}

Since my constraint is quite strong, I don't think there are any Hadamard matrices with entries restricted as above, and I also feel intuitively that the above construction is extremal. However, I'm unable to prove it. But, surely this is already well-known; can anyone help me prove it, or provide a reference for the same?

Comment: These constrained sets of vectors of length $n$ seem to be simply transforms of vectors of length $n/2$: start with such a vector and "negative-duplicate" each element to form the pairs. That immediately implies an upper bound of $n/2$ on the number of such length-$n$ vectors. Moreover, I think any linearly independent set of length-$n/2$ vectors gives rise to such a set, since the pair-duplicated versions are automatically orthogonal. Consider for example only length-$n/2$ vectors of the form $(1,\dots,1,-1,\dots,-1)$ where the number of $1$s varies.

Comment: @GregMartin The second half of your comment makes sense to me: I am able to find $n/2$ vectors having that form that are linearly independent; then, creating from $(a_1,\dots,a_{n/2})$ the vector $(a_1,-a_1,\dots,a_{n/2},-a_{n/2})$, this gives $n/2$ such vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I don't think I understand the argument for the upper bound. Each pair can be placed as either $(a,-a)$ or $(-a,a)$, so there are $2^{n/2}$ ways to create an $n$-vector from an $n/2$-vector. How do you say that the upper bound of $n/2$ is immediate?

Comment: You're right, my upper bound was too hasty. But let me rescue the idea: there is no Hadamard matrix where every row has equal numbers of $1$s and $-1$s, since $(1,\dots,1)$ is in the null space/kernel of such a matrix yet Hadamard matrices are invertible (orthogonal rows implies linearly independent rows). This implies your claim as a special case.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah, that's a neat observation. So, now we know there are at least n/2 such vectors and no more than n-1. It would be great to be able to close the gap completely. :)

Comment: @GregMartin Your observation about these vectors being "negative-duplicate" actually seems to be enough to show $n/2$ as an upper bound as follows. Let $x$ be an $n$-vector that is not of obtained from $n/2$-vectors of the form $(1,\dots,1,-1,\dots,-1)$ as you described. Consider the $n/2$-vector $(x_1,x_3,x_5,\dots)$. This is a linear combination of the $n/2$-vectors we started out with, since they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n/2}$. But then, the same linear combination shows that $x$ is also in the span of the $n$-vectors, because in the other coordinates it's only the sign that is flipped.

Comment: If you'd like to convert these comments into an answer, I'll be happy to upvote and accept it. Else, I'll do so when I get time after the weekend. :)

Comment: Yeah I had drifted back towards believing $n/2$ as well! I'll take you up on your offer to write up the answer yourself this weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on a helpful discussion in the comments under the question with [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin).

---

> I'm trying to show that no Hadamard matrix $H$ can exist under the following restriction on its entries: for each $1 \leq k \leq n/2$, $H_{i,2k-1} \neq H_{i,2k}$, that is, in each row, the consecutive pairs of entries are all $\{\pm1\}$.

Here is a simple way to show that no such Hadamard matrix $H$ can exist. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there is such an $H$. Note that $H$ must be invertible. But, the all-ones vector $(1,\dots,1)$ is in the kernel of $H$, so this is not possible.

> My stronger guess is that there aren't more than $\log_2(n)$ mutually orthogonal $(\pm1)$-vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that $x_{2k-1} \neq x_{2k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n/2$.

One can actually do much better than $\log_2(n)$. Here is a way to achieve a *linear* lower bound. For $1 \leq i \leq n/2$, define $v^{(i)} = \bigl(v^{(i)}_1,\dots,v^{(i)}_{n/2}\bigr) \in \mathbb{R}^{n/2}$ to be the vector $(1,\dots,1,-1,\dots,-1)$ having $i$ ones followed by $\frac{n}{2}-i$ negative ones. Define $x^{(i)} = \bigl(v^{(i)}_1,-v^{(i)}_1,\dots,v^{(i)}_{n/2},-v^{(i)}_{n/2}\bigr) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, clearly $x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(n/2)}$ are $n/2$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the required criterion.

Moreover, this upper bound is tight. To see why, first note that the vectors $v^{(1)},\dots,v^{(n/2)}$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n/2}$. Let $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be any $(\pm1)$-vector satisfying the given condition. Consider the vector $v = (x_1,x_3,\dots,x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n/2}$. Then, $v$ is a linear combination of $v^{(1)},\dots,v^{(n/2)}$. But, the same linear combination also shows that $x$ is a linear combination of $x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(n/2)}$, since $x_{2k} = -x_{2k-1}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n/2$.